# does the new firebase crashlytics platform allow to combine iOS and Android reporting?

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, crashlytics, google-fabric

I know that for Fabric two separate apps are required for Android and iOS even though they can share common codebase (and so common event source) using Ionic/Cordova.

Was unable to figure out from the Firebase Crashlytics documentation if it is possible to combine the reports across iOS/Android and if not if this is considered for the future (I'd appreciate any tickets/threads on this)?

Whats interesting [Fabric to Firebase migration documentation concerning organizing projects for Apple](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/examples/firebase/organizing-projects.html) shows mainly Android apps on screenshots.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't. However, using the BigQuery export you'd be able to report across platforms. This would be useful for cases of aggregation only. Or if you use logs and keys as you'll be able to create custom filters around those.

Comment: have you even read the question & the discussion before down-voting my answer? down-voted your answer - because it completely misses the point. one simply won't export what one cannot collect.